# Java array values being put into wrong array

Tags: java, arrays

The following code runs once through the loop fine, but on the second pass, `theEquation` has had its data changed even though nothing had referenced it.

```
String[] theEquation = breakdown(theequation);
double[] yValues = new double[400];

for(int i=0; i < bitmapx; i++){
    Double v = xmin + (xstep * i);
    yValues[i] = Double.parseDouble( solveArrayX( theEquation , v ) );
}
```

For example, the first time through the for loop, `theEquation` will have `{ "x", "^", "2" }`. The next time will be `{ previousCalculatedAnswer, null, null }`

Why is `theEquation` being changed? No other code is referencing it.

Comment: post the `solveArrayX` method, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing array in method changes array outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653048/changing-array-in-method-changes-array-outside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Why is theEquation being changed?*

`theEquation` does not contain an array, it contains a reference to an array.

When you do `solveArrayX( theEquation , v )` you're passing this reference to the `solveArrayX` method which changes the array. See [lines 120 and 121](http://pastebin.com/3BFKXpNB):

```
public String solveArrayX(String[] tA, double d){
    ...

        tA[i] = tA[i+2];
        tA[i+2] = "";
    ...
}
```

If you want to avoid this, you can use `Arrays.copyOf(theEquation, theEquation.length)` as argument to the method.

Comment: thanks, i knew about arrays being pointers but i didnt know that it extends to functions that you pass the arrays!

Comment: Just from curiosity: where exactly do you see lines 120, 121 in OP question?

Comment: Where did the OP post the link to `solveArrrayX` implementation? Can't find it in the question nor the history.

Comment: @PredragMaric, the OP posted it as a comment. The link is available in my answer.

Comment: I would not have learned about referenced arrays by debugging. I am aware of debugging and have been at my debugger for half the day trying to fix this. Your comments arnt constructive at all.

Comment: Well, you are coming off as a bit harsh. The behaviors of passing arrays is, to me, unintuitive. A debugger would not have helped me pass that mental block because I've been sitting here for hours at my debugger with no luck.

Comment: Ah well, all that's left of @jalynn2 is his down vote now anyway.