# Arrays - Call by reference

Tags: java, arrays

While passing an array to a function in java and then assigning it to a new array, I am getting the same old array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, };
        changes(arr1);
        for (int val : arr1) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }

private static void changes(int[] arr1) {
    int[] arr2 = { 7, 8, 9 };
    arr1 = arr2;
}
```

Why is it so when passing array deals with passing the reference to that array?

Comment: Also look at: [Changing array in method changes array outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653048/changing-array-in-method-changes-array-outside)

Comment: Java is a pass-by-value language. The value of an object is a reference to the object. This includes arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are modifying the reference to `arr1` locally (you can't modify the caller's reference). Change

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

to

```
System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, arr1, 0, arr2.length);
```